# How to reverse the value order of a dependent variable in logistic regression model command

Tags: stata

The dependent variable in my Stata logistic regression is treatment: 0=home hemodialysis and 1=center hemodialysis. The main independent variable is race: 0=white(reference), 1=black, 2=hispanic, 3=asian. The output odds ratio shows minorities are more likely to use center hemodialysis. However, I want to reverse the interpretation. I want to say that minorities are less likely to use home hemodialysis. Therefore, in Stata logistic regression command, which option do I need to use? Use reverse in the end of the command?

Answer (score 0):

> Use reverse in the end of the command?

This specific question seems to imply that there is, or should be, an option `reverse` to do this, but there isn't, as a moment's experiment would show.

For either `logit` or `logistic` you just need to reverse the variable first, which is say

```
gen home = 1 - treatment 
label def home 1 "home hemodialysis" 0 "center hemodialysis"
label val home home 
label var home "Home hemodialysis?"
```

Some Stata users prefer to use `recode` here. Whichever way you do it, you then re-run your model fit command.

Note the small but useful detail of naming an indicator for that state coded 1. You and your readers are not helped by names like `treatment`, which at best raise the question "Which way round did you code your indicator?" and at worst can be very embarrassing. (I have heard many stories of presenters not being able to answer this question from an audience.) For more advice, see https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0099